# panda concat panel data with duplicate items

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, panel, concatenation

I am new to Pandas. I meet a problem that when I concat two panel data, if there are duplicates in the items, it will be double counted. Is there a way I can only pick the item from left if there is a duplicate.

```
from zipline.data.loader import load_bars_from_yahoo
data_1 = load_bars_from_yahoo(stocks = ['GOOG', 'YAHO'], 
                                              indexes={}, start=start,
                                              end=end , adjusted=True)
data_2 = load_bars_from_yahoo(stocks = ['APPL', 'YAHO'], 
                                              indexes={}, start=start,
                                              end=end , adjusted=True)
data = pd.concat([data_1, data_2])
```

data will have items 'GOOG', 'YAHO', 'APPL', 'YAHO'. the question is is there a way to not have duplicates when concat

Comment: Could you please give us an example where you are stuck with your coding? Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information on How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I don't have zipline installed but I think `combine_first()` is all you need.

Comment: combine_first() only can be used for dataframe, panel data don't have this method.